# OneSignal - Can't open closed app by clicking on notification

Tags: android, onesignal

I can't open my app by clicking on a notification in OneSignal. Nothing happens when the app is closed; it only works if I'm in the app (open). I don't get any log errors. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great, I'm stuck on this.

```
public class OneSignalPushApplication extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Logging set to help debug issues, remove before releasing your app.
        //OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.WARN);

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .autoPromptLocation(true)
                .init();
    }

    private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {

            String title=result.notification.payload.title;
            String desc=result.notification.payload.body;

            Log.d("xiomi", "Received Title "+title);
            Log.d("xiomi", "Received Desc "+desc);


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Intro.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("push_title", title);
            intent.putExtra("push_message", desc);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

My `Intro` call that calls `MainActivity` in the end:

```
public class Intro extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getIntent().setAction("Already created");
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        Toast.makeText(this, title , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                EasySplashScreen config = new EasySplashScreen(Intro.this)
                        .withFullScreen()
                        .withTargetActivity(MainActivity.class)
                        .withSplashTimeOut(2000)
                        .withBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spash);


                View easySplashScreenView = config.create();
                setContentView(easySplashScreenView);


        }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       // Log.v("Resume", "onResume");
        super.onResume();
    }

}
```

Manifest of the app:

```
<application ...>
   <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
</application>
```

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105612/onesignal-cannot-open-activity-after-push-clicked?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @MohammadAli still cant open

Comment: any errors in logs ??

Comment: @ALTegani yeaa i got none in the log thats the weird part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Soved by adding the OneSignalPushApplication class inside application tag on the manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name=".OneSignalPushApplication"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```